# Error in .NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

The description for Event ID ( 1000 ) in Source ( .NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting ) cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer, or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer, or contact the component manufacturer for a newer version.

If the event was saved from another computer or forwarded from a remote computer, you might have to include display information with the events when saving them or when setting up the forwarding s application.exe, 3.0.3830.21478, 4c27829c, kernel32.dll, 5.1.2600.5781, 49c4f482, 0, 00012afb.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The computer on which you are viewing the log does not have a EventLog source registered with that name.  So the eventviewer does not know what multi-lingual token substitution to use.
Maybe .Net 2.0 is not installed?
Anyway, try creating a text file and naming it "net2errorreporting.reg" with these contents:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application\.NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting]
"EventMessageFile"="C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\DW\\DW20.EXE"
"TypesSupported"=dword:00000007
```

Make sure the DW20.exe is present in that directory (or update the path in your new file).  Then, right-click on the file in Explorer and click Merge.